# @font-face Issue - Alien League

Tags: css, firefox, font-face

I have two font face styles in my css, both are identical, but only one doesnt work in firefox? i have tried changing the speech marks, adding a local version, changing the files root, and urls, and various other things, i just cant understand why one would work and the other wouldnt, here is my code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'AlienLeague';
src: url('fonts/alien5.eot');
src: url('fonts/alien5.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/alien5.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/alien5.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/alien5.svg#alien5') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

#title {
width: auto;
font-family: "AlienLeague", sans-serif;
font-size: 34px;
color: #fff;
float: left;
margin: 0px 40px 0px 40px;
}
```

I used font squirrel so please dont mention that and heres a link: http://aawilson.co.uk/assign1/ (its the top left heading "space and beyond")

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is weird, I want to say the problem is with the font but I guess it is with the server. If you are using firebug take a look at the response, it's not been identified as a font even though the correct Content-Type is there (application/x-font-woff)

Comment: Did you run the AlienLeague type through a converter?? It COULD be a bad file, since its seems that it SHOULD be working.

Comment: Where did you get the font from? The most natural explanation is that the font is somehow broken.

Comment: I did run it through a converter, you could actually be right about it being a bad file as font-squirrel seems to think its corrupt now, even after using a new file, it has to be only the woff file though, any suggestions? I also got it from the original creators website.